# Generalizing convexity of sets

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Let $X$ be a subset of some Euclidean space. We say that $X$ is *convex* if for any two points $p$, $q$ in $X$, the line segment joining $p$ and $q$ is also in $X$. But what if we loosen this definition a bit, and say that $X$ is *$n$-convex* if for every $p$, $q$, there is a piecewise-linear path from $p$ to $q$ consisting of at most $n$ segments? In this way $1$-convexity would just be convexity. Star convexity would (strictly) be a bit stronger than $2$-convexity. This would be something that's $3$-convex:

[image]

An infinite spiral shape wouldn't be $n$-convex for any $n$.

Have people studied this notion of "$n$-convexity"? This isn't homework or research or anything, I was just curious and I didn't find a quick answer on wikipedia or google.

Comment: Am i right that a set is n-convex (under your definition) iff it can be represented as a union of n convex sets (under usual definition)?

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have an example of a 2-convex set that is not star-convex?

Comment: @Igor: No, a star-convex set is 2-convex but is not necessarily the union of 2 convex sets.

Comment: @Rahul. Really. Thanks

Comment: @Rahul, well maybe star convex and 2-convex are the same, didn't think about that. No I don't have an example of something that's 2-convex but not star convex.

Comment: @Rahul What about square ring?

Comment: @Igor: No, two points in the middle of opposite edges would require three segments. A triangular ring would work though!

Comment: @Rahul How about $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the origin removed? That seems 2-convex but not star convex, right?

Comment: @VikramSaraph You are right.

Comment: So $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the origin is not simply-connected, but it seems that even $n$-connectedness is in general not strong enough to guarantee that a $2$-convex set is star convex. This is because $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ minus origin is $n$-connected and 2-convex but still not star convex. I wonder if contractibility is strong enough to make 2-convexity and star convexity equivalent?

Comment: What would the purpose be of such a generalization? If it is to facilitate non-convex optimization? If so then frankly Igor's description as the union of $n$ convex sets is more functional, and doesn't even require connectedness.

Comment: I didn't have a purpose in mind when I posted this, and I don't know anything about optimization. It just seems like a nice definition that is weaker than convexity and stronger than path-connectedness. I was just curious if it appeared anywhere in math literature since if I've thought of it others surely have as well. (Also, in hindsight I think connectedness is orthogonal to any kind of concept of convexity, since connectedness is a topological property and convexity isn't. Indeed, even contractibility is not enough to force a 2-convex set to be star convex).